# How to count column with condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need help to count pass subject level wise.

The problem is that below query count all the pass subject without checking level and show total count in all level as shown in STUDKEY='0100100003' the student(0100100003) pass 1 subject in level 1, 1 in level 2 and 1 in level 3

```
SELECT 
    s.STUDKEY,
    sb.LEVEL_ID,
    COUNT(sb.SUBJECT_ID) [No of papers], 
    (SELECT count(t.SUBJECT_ID) 
     FROM tab_exam_forms_tran t 
     INNER JOIN tab_exam_forms f1 ON f1.EXAM_FORM_ID = t.EXAM_FORM_ID 
     WHERE t.PASS = 'Y' AND f1.studkey = s.studkey) AS "Pass Paper"
FROM
    TAB_SYLLABUS_SUBJECTS sb 
INNER JOIN 
    TAB_STUDENTS s ON s.SYLLABUS_ID = sb.SYLLABUS_ID
INNER JOIN 
    tab_exam_forms f ON f.studkey=s.studkey and f.session_id='46'
GROUP BY
    s.STUDKEY, sb.LEVEL_ID
ORDER BY
    s.STUDKEY, sb.LEVEL_ID
```

**Current output**

```
STUDKEY    |LEVEL_ID| No of |  Pass
           |        |papers | papers
0100100000 | 1      |1      |0
0100100000 | 2      |2      |0
0100100000 | 3      |2      |0
0100100001 | 1      |1      |0
0100100001 | 2      |2      |0
0100100001 | 3      |2      |0
0100100002 | 1      |1      |0
0100100002 | 2      |2      |0
0100100002 | 3      |2      |0
0100100003 | 1      |1      |3
0100100003 | 2      |2      |3
0100100003 | 3      |2      |3
0100100004 | 1      |1      |0
0100100004 | 2      |2      |0
0100100004 | 3      |2      |0
```

**Expecting output**

```
STUDKEY    |LEVEL_ID| No of |  Pass
           |        |papers | papers
0100100000 | 1      |1      |0
0100100000 | 2      |2      |0
0100100000 | 3      |2      |0
0100100001 | 1      |1      |0
0100100001 | 2      |2      |0
0100100001 | 3      |2      |0
0100100002 | 1      |1      |0
0100100002 | 2      |2      |0
0100100002 | 3      |2      |0
0100100003 | 1      |1      |1
0100100003 | 2      |2      |1
0100100003 | 3      |2      |1
0100100004 | 1      |1      |0
0100100004 | 2      |2      |0
0100100004 | 3      |2      |0
```

[image: tab_exam_forms]
[image: tab_exam_forms_tran]
[image: tab_students][image: tab_syllabus]
[image: tab_syllabus_subjects]

Comment: You need to consider LEVELID for your inner count query.

Comment: you are right i also try this but not getting right result

Comment: please post the table structure and a few sample entries..

Answer (score 1):

In your original query, You can add an additional filter `LEVEL_ID =  s.LEVEL_ID`. For this you will have to join with `TAB_STUDENTS` and `TAB_SYLLABUS_SUBJECTS` in your co-related sub query like this

```
SELECT 
    s.STUDKEY,
    sb.LEVEL_ID,
    COUNT(sb.SUBJECT_ID) [No of papers], 

        (SELECT count(DISTINCT t.SUBJECT_ID) FROM tab_exam_forms_tran t 
        INNER JOIN tab_exam_forms f1 ON f1.EXAM_FORM_ID=t.EXAM_FORM_ID 
        INNER JOIN TAB_STUDENTS s1 ON f1.studkey=s1.studkey and f.session_id='46'
        INNER JOIN TAB_SYLLABUS_SUBJECTS sb1 on s1.SYLLABUS_ID = sb1.SYLLABUS_ID
        WHERE t.PASS='Y' AND f1.studkey=s.studkey AND sb1.LEVEL_ID =  s.LEVEL_ID) AS "Pass Paper"

    from TAB_SYLLABUS_SUBJECTS sb 
    INNER JOIN TAB_STUDENTS s on s.SYLLABUS_ID = sb.SYLLABUS_ID
    INNER JOIN tab_exam_forms f on f.studkey=s.studkey
    group by s.STUDKEY,sb.LEVEL_ID
    order by s.STUDKEY,sb.LEVEL_ID
```

OR, You can do it without the sub query as well. Just use a `CASE` in your parent query like this.

```
SELECT 
    s.STUDKEY,
    sb.LEVEL_ID,
    COUNT(DISTINCT sb.SUBJECT_ID) [No of papers], 
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.PASS='Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "Pass Paper"
    from TAB_SYLLABUS_SUBJECTS sb 
    INNER JOIN TAB_STUDENTS s on s.SYLLABUS_ID = sb.SYLLABUS_ID
    INNER JOIN tab_exam_forms f on f.studkey=s.studkey and f.session_id='46'
    INNER JOIN tab_exam_forms_tran t ON t.EXAM_FORM_ID = f.EXAM_FORM_ID
    group by s.STUDKEY,sb.LEVEL_ID
    order by s.STUDKEY,sb.LEVEL_ID
```

Comment: getting 2 4 4 in pass paper not 1 1 1

Comment: @MuhammadAnas - which one did you try?

Comment: also can edit your question and add some sample input data for `tab_exam_forms_tran `,`tab_exam_forms `,`TAB_STUDENTS ` and `TAB_SYLLABUS_SUBJECTS ` for the student key `0100100003`

Comment: acctually i am using subquery because i want all student that appear in session_id='46' and check for pass paper in all session_id

Comment: can there be multiple `PASS='Y'` records  for the same `STUDKEY` for the same `SUBJECT_ID`

Comment: Try `count(DISTINCT t.SUBJECT_ID)` in the sub-query. updated answer

Comment: student can pass a paper once, how can i upload sample table data screenshot in comment

Comment: @MuhammadAnas, without sample data to play with, all we're gonna do is guess. Please post sample data that matches with your expected result.

Comment: please don't post the sample data as a comment. you can **edit** the question and add the sample data there

Answer (score 0):

You need to revise your table structure.

**There is no distinction for papers as per level in table tab_exam_forms_tran**

You are using Level ID in table TAB_SYLLABUS_SUBJECTS, but it has no linkup with 'tab_exam_forms' and 'ab_exam_forms_tran'

**In my opinion :**

1. You need to have Level ID in tables 'tab_exam_forms' and 'ab_exam_forms_tran' and use that column in joins

   OR
2. Primary id of table TAB_SYLLABUS_SUBJECTS as foreign key in tables 'tab_exam_forms' and 'ab_exam_forms_tran' and use it in joins